# HashTable Keys Not Found, Special Character (Like "@") Handling, Escaping

Tags: vb.net, escaping, key, hashtable

I have a *HashTable* in **VB.NET** and dynamically add records to it with keys that are strings in plain ASCII, but include sometimes special characters like "**@**" etc. I have a bunch of keys that start with the "**@**" character and it is not problem to add them the *HashTable*

```
Public Class MyHash
    Inherits Collections.Hashtable

    Sub New()

       'Data coming from DB
        me.Add(key, value)

       'for example:
       '  me.add("@key", "value")
    End Sub

End Class
```

That works fine.... looking at the object in the debugger shows the item with the key "**@key**" as an element of the *HashTable* collection. However...

```
MyHash("@key")
```

Returns "**Nothing**" also

```
MyHash.ContainsKey("@key")
```

Returns "**False**".

I don't want to replace the special characters with something else, because those characters are the key as it is.. anything else would be something different and creating a whole new set of issues down the road.

**Is There a way to escape the Key** value during addition to the *HashTable* or lookup, or maybe a configuration flag that I can set for the inherited class, e.g. a compiler attribute or something to make it work and find all records with any key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following code in a new console project:

```
Module Module1
Public Class MyHash
    Inherits Collections.Hashtable

    Sub New()

        'Data coming from DB
        Me.Add("@key", "value")
    End Sub

End Class


Sub Main()
    Dim h As New MyHash
    Debug.Assert(h.ContainsKey("@key"))
    Debug.Assert(h("@key") = "value")
End Sub
End Module
```

All work as you expect (even in watch window).
The '@' symbol doesn't need any escape.

Just be sure, since theese data comes from db, that the key is exactly "@key" (e.g. spaces at end). After reading key and value pair, I suggest you to check:

```
Debug.Assert(key.Trim.Equals("@key"))
Debug.Assert(key.Equals("@key"))
```

If the first assert is true and the second fails, then you know there's some space at the beginning and/or at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, I have to admit my own mistake.. the data from the database contained a © character (copyright), which I had mistaken from the @ character ("AT"). I am sorry for that.